# Add debounce function to buttons in arduino code

Tags: button, arduino, debouncing

I have made a transmission controller and the code works fine as it is. But i would like to add debounce function into to the code, since the shifts would somethimes not be recognised when pushing the buttons. I am far from a good coder, so this code is very simple and I understand everything in it. But I cant figure out how to add debounce to the buttons without advancing the code too much for me too not understand it anymore.

Could anyone come with any help or tips please? See attached code.

```
int gear = 1;
// output pins for transistor controlled solenoids
int solA = 4;
int solB = 5;
int solC = 6;
int solD = 7;
int solE = 8;
int solTCC = 9;
int solLinePress = 10;
// input pins for up down /  with pullup resistors
int gearup = 2;
int geardown = 3;

// Pin out for single 7 digit display
int a=22; 
int b=23; 
int c=24; 
int d=25; 
int e=26; 
int f=27; 
int g=28;

void setup() {
  pinMode(solA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(solB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(solC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(solD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(solE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(solTCC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(solLinePress, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(gearup, INPUT);
  pinMode(geardown, INPUT);
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(c, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(d, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(e, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(f, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(g, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

 if(gear == -1){ // Reverse

    digitalWrite(solA, 1);
    digitalWrite(solB, 1);
    digitalWrite(solC, 1);
    digitalWrite(solD, 0);
    digitalWrite(solE, 1);
    digitalWrite(solTCC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solLinePress, 0);

    digitalWrite(a, LOW);
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH);

  }
      if(gear == 0){ // Neutral

    digitalWrite(solA, 1);
    digitalWrite(solB, 1);
    digitalWrite(solC, 1);
    digitalWrite(solD, 1);
    digitalWrite(solE, 1);
    digitalWrite(solTCC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solLinePress, 0);

    digitalWrite(a, LOW);
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    digitalWrite(d, LOW);
    digitalWrite(e, LOW);
    digitalWrite(f, LOW);
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH);

  }

  if(gear == 1){ // 1th gear

    digitalWrite(solA, 1);
    digitalWrite(solB, 1);
    digitalWrite(solC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solD, 1);
    digitalWrite(solE, 1);
    digitalWrite(solTCC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solLinePress, 0);

    digitalWrite(a, LOW);
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(d, LOW);
    digitalWrite(e, LOW);
    digitalWrite(f, LOW);
    digitalWrite(g, LOW);

  }
  if(gear == 2){ // 2nd Gear

    digitalWrite(solA, 1);
    digitalWrite(solB, 1);
    digitalWrite(solC, 1);
    digitalWrite(solD, 1);
    digitalWrite(solE, 0);
    digitalWrite(solTCC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solLinePress, 0);

    digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(f, LOW);
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
  }
  if(gear == 3){ // 3rd Gear

    digitalWrite(solA, 0);
    digitalWrite(solB, 1);
    digitalWrite(solC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solD, 1);
    digitalWrite(solE, 0);
    digitalWrite(solTCC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solLinePress, 0);

    digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(e, LOW);
    digitalWrite(f, LOW);
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH);

  }
  if(gear == 4){ // 4th Gear

    digitalWrite(solA, 0);
    digitalWrite(solB, 1);
    digitalWrite(solC, 1);
    digitalWrite(solD, 0);
    digitalWrite(solE, 0);
    digitalWrite(solTCC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solLinePress, 0);

    digitalWrite(a, LOW);
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(d, LOW);
    digitalWrite(e, LOW);
    digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH);

 }
  if(gear == 5){ // 5th Gear

    digitalWrite(solA, 0);
    digitalWrite(solB, 1);
    digitalWrite(solC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solD, 0);
    digitalWrite(solE, 1);
    digitalWrite(solTCC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solLinePress, 0);

    digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(e, LOW);
    digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
     }
  if(gear == 6){ / // 6th Gear

    digitalWrite(solA, 0);
    digitalWrite(solB, 0);
    digitalWrite(solC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solD, 0);
    digitalWrite(solE, 0);
    digitalWrite(solTCC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solLinePress, 0);

    digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH);

     }
  if(gear == 7){ // 7th Gear

    digitalWrite(solA, 1);
    digitalWrite(solB, 0);
    digitalWrite(solC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solD, 0);
    digitalWrite(solE, 1);
    digitalWrite(solTCC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solLinePress, 0);

    digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(d, LOW);
    digitalWrite(e, LOW);
    digitalWrite(f, LOW);
    digitalWrite(g, LOW);


       }
  if(gear == 8){ // 8th Gear

    digitalWrite(solA, 1);
    digitalWrite(solB, 0);
    digitalWrite(solC, 1);
    digitalWrite(solD, 0);
    digitalWrite(solE, 0);
    digitalWrite(solTCC, 0);
    digitalWrite(solLinePress, 0);

    digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH);


  }



  //takes care of gear switching

  delay(150); //delay to prevent going through gears too quick from holding the button or pressing too long

  gear += digitalRead(geardown) - digitalRead(gearup); // non debounced! But may not be a problem because of the delay by gear change
  if(gear < -1) gear = -1;
  if(gear > 8) gear = 8;
  //limits to actual gearset


}
```

Comment: Adafruit has a learning section [Debouncing](https://learn.adafruit.com/make-it-switch/debouncing) may be useful for you to learn the subject.

Comment: It may not be debounce you need but a loop to detect the button push on a much faster frequency.  If this loop takes 1ms to run and then you wait 150ms between samples of the button, you have to be pretty precise with the button or hold it down for more that 150ms so it gets sampled.

Answer (score 0):

Because the question asks specifically about how to debounce i will link you [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce) to the official arduino example that is also contained in the IDE, libraries exist online with a brief search i found this [one](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Bounce/) and you could also hardware debounce the inputs using resistors and capacitors.